# Blender Exported .dxf has geometry missing in AutoCAD

Tags: export, file-format

I have a blender file, I want to export .dxf file

In the blender I select export in *File-> export -> .dxf*, but when I open the .dxf file by AutoCad, some objects are missing

In Blender

[image]

After export to .dxf, and open in AutoCad

[image]

Anyone know can just help me with

Thank you

Comment: This is no error you are probably exporting unsupported geometry or object types. What kind of object are those arcs?